# Form onSubmit() not being called after upgrade to Wicket 7

Tags: java, wicket

I'm in the process of upgrading our web app to use Wicket 7 (was using 6.19).

The first page is a login screen, but for some reason, the form's `onSubmit()` method isn't being called, so on clicking the submit button, I just get the login page re-displayed.

I've consulted the Wicket 7 [migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+7.0#MigrationtoWicket7.0-RenamePageSettings#recreateMountedPagesAfterExpiryto#recreateBookmarkablePagesAfterExpiryWICKET-5829), which doesn't mention any specific changes in this area.

It's a pretty straightforward case, as you can see, it's a simple form containing username and password fields

```
    <form wicket:id="loginform" id="loginform" >
        <table style="display: table; border: 0px; margin: auto;">
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="login" colspan="2"><span wicket:id="feedback">Feedback</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="login">
                    <label for="username"><wicket:message key="username">Username</wicket:message>:&nbsp;</label>
                </td>
                <td class="login">
                    <input wicket:id="username" id="username" type="text" name="user" value="" size="30" maxlength="50"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="login">
                    <label for="password"><wicket:message key="password">Password</wicket:message>:&nbsp;</label>
                </td>
                <td class="login">
                    <input wicket:id="password" id="password" type="password" name="pswd" value="" size="30" maxlength="16"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="login">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="login"><input class="btn" type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" wicket:message="title:loginButtonTitle"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Here's the Java code setting up the page components -

```
public class Login extends UnSecurePageTemplate {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7202246935258483555L;

@SpringBean private IBrandingService brandingService;
@SpringBean private IRemonService remonService;
@SpringBean private IUserAdminService userAdminService ;

private static final Logger logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger( Login.class);

public Login()  {
    this(new PageParameters());
}

public Login(PageParameters pageParameters) {
    super(pageParameters);


    BrandingThemeProperties properties = brandingService.getBrandingThemeProperties();

    String welcomeLabel = properties.getProperty("welcome-label");

    add(new Label("welcome", welcomeLabel));
    add(new Label("loginHeader", getStringFromPropertiesFile("loginInstruction", this)));

    LoginForm form = new LoginForm("loginform", new SimpleUser(), pageParameters);
    form.add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));

    add(form);
}
```

And here's the Login form (the `login()` method authenticates the user and returns another page) -

```
public final class LoginForm extends Form<SimpleUser>
{
    PageParameters pageParameters;

    public LoginForm(String id, SimpleUser simpleUser, PageParameters pageParameters)
    {
        super(id, new CompoundPropertyModel<SimpleUser>(simpleUser));
        this.pageParameters = pageParameters;

        add(new TextField<String>("username").setRequired(true).add(StringValidator.maximumLength(50)));
        add(new PasswordTextField("password").setResetPassword(true).add(StringValidator.maximumLength(50)));

   }


    /**
     * Called upon form submit. Attempts to authenticate the user.
     */
    protected void onSubmit()
    {
        SimpleUser user = getModel().getObject();
        String username = user.getUsername();
        String password = user.getPassword();

        login(username, password, pageParameters);
    }
}
```

I also tried using a submit Button, but its `onSubmit()` wasn't called either.

Comment: If `onSubmit()` is not called then maybe `onError()` is. Put a breakpoint at Form#onFormSubmitted() and see what happens.

Comment: Form.onFormSubmitted() is never called

Comment: onError() isn't called either. No error reported in the log. No exception thrown.

Comment: What's the answer of the ajax response?

Comment: @ThorstenWendelmuth There is no Ajax, as far as I can see. What is the url of <form action="...."> ?

Comment: <form id="loginform" method="post" action="./login">

Comment: The confusing thing is, that this worked with Wicket 6. And so I can only assume that my modifications for Wicket 7 have broken something. So I was trying to trace the call hierarchy for onFormSubmitted() being called, but nothing in the framework appears to call it directly. If you can give me a clue for placement of breakpoints to trace this, that would be useful.

Comment: Ok so this is causing the problem, but I don't know why. In our WebApplication class, the page was mounted like this
mount(new NoVersionMount("/login", Login.class)); which causes the problem. But the following works better mountPage("/login", Login.class); So our version of the MountedMapper class is causing a problem with form submission.

Comment: In our MountedMapper class we had overriden the encodePageComponentInfo() method, to do nothing, for some reason.  Once I commented this out, it worked    @Override protected void encodePageComponentInfo(Url url,
                                                     PageComponentInfo info) {
        // do nothing so that component info does not get
        // rendered in url
    }

Comment: I wish this was written as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Also, by default PasswordTextField has a validator that requires at least one character. If you don't enter any text in the field, then validation fails, and your onSubmit method does not get called. You can avoid the problem by calling new PasswordTextField("pwd").setRequired(false)